# Running an M-X command automatically

Tags: themes

Every time I open emacs I run the following set of commands:

```
M-X
load-theme
danneskjold
```

I wanted to set things up so this happens *automatically*

I put the following things ~/emacs.d/init.el file

```
(package-initialize)
(load-theme 'danneskjold t)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ...init.el

Symbol's function definition is void: package-initialize

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Also tried the following in init.el file

```
(load-theme 'danneskjold t)
```

Get a different error message:

```
Wrong number of arguments: #[(theme) ^H\211^X   >)\203^_^@\304^H!\210\305^H\306\307#\210\305^H\310\307#\210\305^H\311\307#\210\312!\203+^@^KB\202,^@^K^[\313\314\315^H!!!)\207
[theme custom-known-themes custom-theme-directory load-path disable-theme put theme-settings nil theme-feature theme-documentation file-directory-p load symbol-name custom-make-theme-feature] 5 1722891 SCustom theme name: ], 2
```

Not really sure what all the symbols are supposed to mean, is there something else going wrong with my emacs?

Comment: I think you're missing `(require 'package)` before `(package-initialize)`

Comment: @FelipeLema I do this and get the following error: File error: Cannot open load file, package. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Have you tried emacs suggestion to start with the `--debug-init` option?

Comment: You're apparently using an Emacs < 24, where package.el is not bundled.  As for the `load-theme` problem, just don't pass the `t` argument.